# calling a blocking method call with timeout in java

Tags: java, java.util.concurrent, concurrent-programming

I want to call a method in java which blocks for some reason. I want to wait for the method for X minutes and then I want to stop that method.

I have read one solution here on StackOverflow which gave me a first quick start. I am writing that here :-

```
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
    Callable<Object> task = new Callable<Object>() {
       public Object call() {
          return something.blockingMethod();
       }
    };
    Future<Object> future = executor.submit(task);
    try {
       Object result = future.get(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS); 
    } catch (TimeoutException ex) {
       // handle the timeout
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
       // handle the interrupts
    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
       // handle other exceptions
    } finally {
       future.cancel(); // may or may not desire this
    }
```

But now my problem is, my function can throw some Exception which I have to catch and do some task accordingly. So if in code the function blockingMethod() thorws some exception how do I catch them in Outer class ?

Comment: I would catch it in the anoymous class. This way there is no exception to catch.

Comment: Also, don't explicitly catch each and every checked exception because you're probably not going to write any specific handling code. Just write `catch (RuntimeException e) { throw e; } catch (Exception e) { throw new RuntimeException(e); }`

Comment: Yes Earlier I thought same thing, I would have done that but there are lots of variable of outer class which I wanted to use in exception handling code. And I am not able to access those variables in Inner class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have everything set up to do that in the code you provide. Just replace

```
// handle other exceptions
```

with your exception handling.
If you need to get your specific `Exception` you get it with:

```
Throwable t = e.getCause();
```

And to differentiate between your Exceptions you can do like this:

```
if (t instanceof MyException1) {
  ...
} else if (t instanceof MyException2) {
  ...
...
```

Comment: I did not know that I will do that for sure :)

Just one more question, if I have different types of Exception for Example 
MyException1, MyException2 and I have to different treatments according to different Exception. How do I differentiate between multiple Exceptions ?

Answer (score 1):

In `cause` of [ExecutionException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutionException.html) instance, I suppose.

Answer (score 1):

In the `ExecutionException` catch block: `e.getCause()`

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html#getCause

Answer (score -1):

thread.sleep(x millisecods) will stop the thread for x milliseconds, then it will resume.  The other way to do it is to call thread.wait(x) (with a timeout value for x) and then call thread.notify() to "wake" the sleeping thread.